# 'Auto Blend Layers' is not working on my Photoshop. How can I make it work?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was trying to swap face with Adobe Photoshop. But I always end up on **Auto-blend layers** on the Edit section.
[image]

Comment: Please post image

Comment: @Rajeevbbqq Done

Answer (score 1):

**Autoblend Way**

```
 1. Select layer 1 and apply proper feathering
 2. Select both layers (layer 1 and layer 2)
 3. Apply auto blend
```

Using auto blend the perfection will be poor.

**Manual Way**

[image: Here I'm going to blend Bush and Trump]

[image: Blended]

```
 1. Select Face of bush without feathering
 2. Paste bush's face to trump's face
 3. Select a round-edged brush ( Select brush tool and right click to
    get brush options )
 4. Erase bush's face
 5. Transform bush's face properly ( CTRL + T to transform )
```

*Please refer the below screenshot*

[image: Blending manually]

Comment: How can I select layer 1 and apply proper feathering?

Comment: By using lasso tool ( L )  and right click and select feather